# moq durable function IDurableOrchestrationContext when Setup CallActivityAsync always returning a null

Tags: c#, moq, azure-durable-functions

I have a Durable Orchestrator function which returns a list from an activity function:

```
var returnList = await context.CallActivityAsync<List<MyObject>>("Activity", (input, context.InstanceId));
```

I have my xUnit Test setup as follows

```
var mock = new Mock<IDurableOrchestrationContext>();

var mockLogger = new Mock<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger>();

var _returnList = new List<MyObject>();

mock.Setup(x=>x.CallActivityAsync<List<MyObject>("Activity",It.IsAny<Object>, string>>())).ReturnsAsync(_returnList);

var orch = new MyOrchestration();

await orc.Run(mock.Object,mockLogger.Object);
```

The Durable Functions Orchestrator Function always returns null where I want it to use the **_returnList** - Any help is appreciated.

Note: I am using DI so my orchestration and activity function are not static.

Comment: Something does not look right with that shown Setup.

Comment: what do you mean - where do you think its wrong?

Comment: Recheck the syntax used in the shown setup. Will that compile?

Answer (score 4):

Solved. Problem was the line

```
mock
    .Setup(x=>x.CallActivityAsync<List<MyObject>("Activity",It.IsAny<Object>, string>>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(_returnList);
```

should of been

```
mock
    .Setup(x => x.CallActivityAsync<List<MyObject>>("Activity",It.IsAny<(List<MyObject>, string)>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(_returnList);
```